# Spring security - new access token

Tags: authentication, spring-security, access-token, multi-tenant

I have following issue.

I have multitenant system (with shared Database and shared Schema). Access token that is generated when user logs in contains information about tenantId. Idea is to allow logged user to change tenat

For example: My user works for 3 tenants(hospitals). When he is logged in, he should be able to change hospital.

So the main issues is how to generate new acces token for user that will contain updated tenantId.
It would be preferable that user doesnt have to provide password again (since he is already logged in), and that request to auth-server that he triggers would contain his current token (that will confirm that he is currently authenticated) and newTenandId.

Here is some custom code:

```
@Service
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    
    @Autowired
    private MessageSource validationMessageSource;
    
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
        
        SpringSecurityUserWithAdditionalData user = (SpringSecurityUserWithAdditionalData) userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        
        return checkPassword(user, password);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
    
    private Authentication checkPassword(SpringSecurityUserWithAdditionalData user, String rawPassword) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            if (passwordEncoder.matches(rawPassword, user.getPassword())) {
                
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities());
                
                return token;
            } else {
                throw new GeneralException(validationMessageSource.getMessage("security.authentication.NotValid", new Object[] {}, LocaleContextHolder.getLocaleContext().getLocale()));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException(e.getMessage());
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration {
    
    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    
    // @formatter:off 
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            ...
            .and()
                .logout()
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(new CustomLogoutSuccessHandler())
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginPage("/changeTenant")
                .permitAll().and();
        return http.build();
    }
    // @formatter:on
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Autowired
    public void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }
    
    /**
     * JWT koji je generisao authorization server sadrzi granted permissions (Spring ih naziva granted authorities) u okviru "scope" claim-a. 
     * Umesto njega cemo koristiti custom claim koji sam nazvao GlobalConstants.JWT_CLAIM_ROLA_LIST za specifikaciju rola koje ima authenticated korisnik.
     * Spring koristi default instance JwtAuthenticationConverter koja ocekuje granted authorities u okviru "scope"/"scp" claim-a. 
     * Da bi koristili umesto standardno "scope" claim-a koristili claim GlobalConstants.JWT_CLAIM_ROLA_LIST override-ovan je JwtAuthenticationConverter.
     */
    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter converter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
        converter.setAuthoritiesClaimName(GlobalConstants.JWT_CLAIM_ROLA_LIST); // override authorities claim-a
        converter.setAuthorityPrefix(""); // eksplicitno definisemo nazive, bez podrazumevanih prefiksa (ROLE_ SCOPE_ i slicno)
        
        JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(converter);
        return jwtConverter;
    }
    
    @Bean
    InitializingBean forcePostProcessor(BeanPostProcessor meterRegistryPostProcessor, MeterRegistry registry) {
        return () -> meterRegistryPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(registry, "");
    }
    
}
```

If you need any additional information, please say.

I tried adding custom fields to custom login form, that will have hidden tenantId field. But i could not manage to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The authentication process should be designed to return a list of all the tenants the user has access to, typically as a list of authorities.

Separately you need a back-end call (linked to the UI) that allows the user to choose the current tenant from the list of authorities returned in authn.

The value of the current tenant must be stored in the session.

Comment: Thanks for answer John.Unfortunately, that cannot be done for this reason. I have multiple microservices, and only one of them (core API) is aware what is last selected tenant. So if the request comes to one of the other microservices they would not be able to know what tenant is currently selected. Since the token would only have a list of all available tenants for that user.

Comment: please dont add additional claims after you asked the question Igor. You need to disclose all the information needed for us to answer so that we dont provide answers and then you suddenly go "oh i cant do this because of... insert new undisclosed information here"

Comment: sorry about that

Comment: So each of the microservices needs to know what the user's current tenant is. Sounds like a shared cache (Hazelcast, Redis) or perhaps the DB would work.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to hack this via the auth roles, you could store the real auth token and generate your own token with only the current tenant. When user changes tenant they get a new token with the new tenant (obviously after checking against the real token)